# Is Stack Overflow not here to help 'newbs' like me asking somewhat articulate questions?

Tags: discussion, stack-overflow, new-users

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20451222/convert-php-mysqli-prepared-statement-to-postgresql-prepared-statement?noredirect=1#comment30574419_20451222

I titled my question - as a single question - but for convenience of the community I clearly described the parts of converting the included PHP MySQLi prepared statements to PHP PostgreSQL statements that I'm having trouble with. And I included descriptions of what each code block did, commenting my working MySQLi statements and using <--- arrows with text following to point out which functions I was having trouble substituting.

I made an effort to read the right docs and even searched two books on the subject before posting too. And I have seen many posts on Stack Overflow where people have simply asked for someone to write them code from scratch without such effort as I put in, and others have helped.

Instead I got harassed by one of the commenters for not 'RTFM' and the one that answered part of my question but preferred me to use PDO, lectured me about not asking the right question, reading the docs, etc. and then officiously tried to cull the comment history and paint my 'expectations' for an answer as going beyond my original question.

Why bother using Stack Overflow when people like this feel entitled to denigrate people asking questions that are framed as articulately as they can within their current knowledge of the subject?

I feel their comments go directly against the original purpose of this site and its community.

Comment: Having read their comments as well as yours, I have to say that I don't see the issues you bring up. I've deleted your comment underneath the question because it was textbook 'not constructive'.

Comment: I have to agree with Craig's comments under the deleted answer: there's too many questions for one post. It would be better to split out each of them to stand on its own. As he also said, items 4 and 5 should be expanded upon.

Comment: Oh and yeah, multiple questions in one are not encouraged on Stack Overflow, as it's aiming to be a repository of Q&A for future generations. Consider splitting them up.

Comment: (FWIW, the original comment here was supposed to be a self-deprecating reflection on how so many of us - myself most definitely included - tend to write MORE when we should be refining what we've ALREADY written. It wasn't interpreted that way...)

Comment: You misunderstand the purpose of the site -- the idea is to help everybody, not just one person.  Writing "here is my code, help me make it go" will help just you.  Writing "trying to do X, but error Y occurred" will help you and every future person searching the web for "error Y" and that's the real purpose of [so].  Try to write questions with that in mind.

Comment: @stckxchgusr We want to help you.  Please take a moment, take a step back and realize that we're not here to attack you or to make you feel unwelcome. We want to help you understand how Stack Overflow works.  We do not tolerate or condone personal attacks here.  I'm going to lock this question for some time to give everyone a chance to cool down.

Answer (score 24):

You asked five separate questions (you were even nice enough to number them), and posted a bunch of irrelevant information. The question itself should be closed as "too broad", until you edit it to reduce it to a single question that can clearly be answered. (I've voted to do so, BTW.)

The only thing I see wrong with Craig's posted answer is that it shouldn't have been made in the first place, because your question isn't specific enough to be answered. The allegations about the conduct of Craig and Deni, both here and in the comments on the deleted answer, are simply unfounded. Craig in fact went out of his way to try and be extremely helpful to you.

As you're wanting to point out the "intent of this site", I'd like to point out that your comment to your own question that makes a personal attack toward Craig and Deni, referring to their " laziness and arrogance", is a direct violation of the StackExchange guidelines and violates the intent of this site. (A moderator has since deleted it for that reason.)

Edit: In response to your "censorship" allegation in the comment, no one "deleted" your question. It is still available; it's been put on hold as "too broad", and is waiting for you to edit it to make it an answerable question here. If that isn't done, it will eventually be closed (and probably deleted by readers at some point for having no future value here).

Craig deleted his own answer to your question, presumably after his repeated attempts to help you were clearly not appreciated. Here's the evidence that it was deleted by Craig:

[image: Self deleted answer with timestamp]

Comment: Wow, you've deleted my post that pointed out the whitewash you've made of Denis's bullying and Craig's supporting of this because I didn't accept his partial as the full answer. I've lost all respect for this site. All deleted comments have been screen-grabbed and emailed to a prominent blogger for more public discussion. The censorship on your part and that of George is offensive, not to forget that the actual bully Denis got to vote and put his name on placing my original question on hold. The fact that someone like Denis can be a bully in comments and place that question on hold is absurd.

Comment: The irony is... had I just written in my original post... 'Please help me convert these 2 small typical php mysqli prepared statements to php postgresql statements, I'm a nub and I'm stuck... and I can't/don't want to use PDO'... someone else would have likely answered with the code. I've seen this so many times. Instead I actually took the time to show where I was stuck by just breaking down my single question into sub-parts, 'sub-questions', and get wrongly criticised for that, told I should use PDO, and bullied by Denis to accept a partial answer and then told by him to 'RTFM'. SpamOverFlow

Comment: @stckxchgusr: You seem to be somewhat confused. Your question has not been deleted; Craig deleted his own **answer** after his efforts to help you were met with abusive comments from you. Neither Craig or Deni "bullied" you in any way, and Craig's answer (and the comments to it) are still visible to readers with sufficient rep. No one has "censored you" in any way; as I said, your question is still there. It's just been put on hold because it's too broad in scope and needs you to edit it to improve it. If you choose not to do so, it will close (and probably end up deleted as having no value).

Comment: How is Denis's first comment telling me in no uncertain language to accept Craig's answer, and then next telling me to 'RTFM'... good 'conduct' and not bullying? Even Craig referred to his post as 'rude'. And then you and this site let that bully place my question on hold. Absurd! I think there are many questions on this site that are closed or placed on hold for specious reasons - often mostly because a few people in the community want to earn some points/badge/honour for being 'seen' to do something. Whereas if they left those questions be answered, this site and the community would benefit.

Comment: @stckxchgusr: "Bullying" requires some sort of threat ("do what I say or..."); Deni made a suggestion. The reason your question was closed is exactly what you have been told several times now here (and in the box beneath your closed question that explains why it was put on hold): It's too broad in scope to be answered. I've addressed the only thing Craig did wrong in my answer here (see the second paragraph above) - I'll repeat it also: He should not have attempted to answer your question in the first place, because it was several questions and too broad in scope.